# I can't determine the polynomial interpolation with the minumum grade

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, numerical-computing

I have to restrict it with the folowings: 
P(-1) = f(-1), P(0)=f(0), P(1)=f(1), P'(1)=f'(1)

Comment: You have four requirements and therefore need a polynomial with four degrees of freedom; this implies a cubic which has four coefficients that uniquely define it.  You find the four coefficients by setting the polynomial and its derivatives equal to your `f` values at their associated points and solving the linear system.  Note: without code, this is more of a math question and fairly off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the polynomial be

```
ax³ + bx² + cx + d
```

By the given equations,

```
- a + b - c + d = f(-1)
              d = f(0)
  a + b + c + d = f(1)
 3a +2b + c     = f'(1)
```

You should be able to solve.